# Correct way to use Go Pprof to compare execution-time differences in two versions of a same functionality

Tags: postgresql, go, pprof, pgx

I am running a Golang project in a container environment which has two pods.

1. Pod1: user-interaction and data-access layer.
2. Pod2: Database server.

The data-access layer involves functions like data validation, do get on db to check if data already exist, insert data, and many more data manipulation tasks...

**I have two versions of the project with two differnt databases. (Database APIs in data-access layers are abstracted so that I can replace the redis with postgres or any other databases.)**

1. Redis db (data access layer implemented with redis package).
2. Postgresql db (data access layer implemented with pgx package).

Now to compare the two versions I ran a command at pod1 to create 100000 records in each, and observed huge difference in command execution time.

- Redis: 2m30s
- Postgres: 9m20s

I need to debug which part of the code is taking more time, so what is the correct way to use Pprof tool? (should I run pprof for entire time of the command execution and compare? or should I run both for a minute and compare?, which pprof profiling should I use?).

Thanks

Comment: for similar operations, redis will generally be faster than a rdbms, so debugging wont help much  in reducing pgx version times to redis version times.

Comment: Instead profiling both clients separately, would be a better way to approach this. e.g. for bringing pgx from 9m20s to lower.